# Removing 0 frequency label from histogram in R

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I am new to r and am looking for help formatting the labels on a histogram I am creating for my stats class. My tasks were to create a histogram for the data that has the numbers on the x axis centered with the bars as well as correctly formatted frequency labels, but I cannot seem to figure out how to remove that 0 at the left end of the axis.

Here is my data:

```
disc.errors<-c(rep.int(0,41),rep.int(1,31),rep.int(2,15),rep.int(3,8),rep.int(4,5))
```

Here is my code for the histogram so far also:

```
hist(x=disc.errors, freq=TRUE, labels=TRUE, main="Disc Errors",
     xlab = "Number of Errors", ylab = "Number of Discs",
     ylim = c(0,50), breaks=c(-0.5, seq(-0.5,5, 1,)))
```

[image: My current histogram]

If anyone also has any tips on easier ways to format my axis so the labels are centered under the bars please include those as well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you doubled up -0.5 in your breaks:

```
breaks=c(-0.5, seq(-0.5,5, 1,))
breaks
[1] -0.5 -0.5  0.5  1.5  2.5  3.5  4.5
```

Because of this, the plot actually has *2* bars centered on -0.5, one of which gets all 41 points and the other gets 0. Since they both have the same position, they overlap and it looks like an extra 0.

Just remove the extra item in breaks to get rid of it:

```
hist(x=disc.errors, freq=TRUE, labels=TRUE, main="Disc Errors",
     xlab = "Number of Errors", ylab = "Number of Discs",
     ylim = c(0,50), breaks=c(seq(-0.5,5, 1,)))
```

[image]